# Is there a way to wrap a long phrase beside an 'inline-block' styled <b> tag?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to wrap long texts beside labels (in this context b tags being used as labels. please look at below code to understand better) such a way that the next line starts just below the first word of the long text.

**NOTE:** I'm using CSS framework Bootstrap.

```css
.patient-details {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p><b class="patient-details">Patient Name </b>: <i>A Looooooonnnnnngggggg Naaaammmee</i></p>
    <p><b class="patient-details">C/o-(Brought By) </b>: P S S Raj</p>
    <p><b class="patient-details">Contact Number </b>: 90********</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p><b class="patient-details">Patient ID </b>: 1</p>
    <p><b class="patient-details">Patient Gender </b>: Male</p>
    <p><b class="patient-details">Patient Age </b>: 18 Yrs</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <p><b class="patient-details">Address </b>: <i>A Verrrrryyyyyyy Loooooooonnnnnggggggg Addddddddddddddrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeesssssssssssssss</i></p>
</div>
```

I tried aligning patient details beside labels(namely the b tags)

When in print preview mode(ctrl + p) the expected output is given below:

```
Patient Name     : A Looooooonnnnnngggggg     Patient ID    : 1
                   Naaaammmee
C/o-(Brought By) : P S S Raj                  Patient Gender: Male
Contact Number   : 90********                 Patient Age   : 18Yrs

Patient Address  : A Verrrrryyyyyyy Loooooooonnnnnggggggg
                   Addddddddddddddrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeesssssssssssssss
```

But the output in print preview mode(ctrl + p) I got is a bit different, like given below:

```
Patient Name    : A Looooooonnnnnngggggg          Patient ID    : 1
Naaaammmee
C/o-(Brought By): P S S Raj                       Patient Gender: Male
Contact Number  : 90********                      Patient Age   : 18Yrs

Patient Address : A Verrrrryyyyyyy Loooooooonnnnnggggggg
Addddddddddddddrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeesssssssssssssss
```

Like shown above I want the long texts beside the "Patient Name" and "Patient Address" to wrap and start a new line from just below the first word of the long text.

I tried adding some inline CSS to the `i` tag, like `position: absolute` but it just isn't working. Any Ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a problem solved by [tag:css-grid].

Comment: if you put your colon inside the b tag and wrap your text on the right in a span, you could make your p flex

Comment: In this situation it would be perfectly arguable to use a table, which would solve that problem too.

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

##### Is there a way to wrap a long phrase beside an 'inline-block' styled  tag?

It is **possible but** not with the current solution.

Example of current solution: `<p><b class="patient-details">Contact Number </b>: 90********</p>`

Your desired effect is **impossible if** you wrap your label (`<b>`)  with a paragraph (`<p>`). This is because the `<p>` tag, and many other physical objects, are displayed in a special container known as "content". *(check out [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_boxmodel.asp))*.

Any long phrase on collapse will start a new line in the content. Usually, by default, a new line starts horizontally from left-to-right. *(Unless specified for a specific language such as Arabic)*.

Do you see the problem :) ? The label is inside that content, and there is nothing we can do to escape it. But **there are alternative ways** to re-create your desired text wrapper.

Some notable solutions: Use [**CSS Grid Layout Module**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp), [**CSS Flexbox**](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp), and classic use of [**HTML Tables**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)
(Credits: [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas), [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete) and [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641669/johannes)),

The key is to separate the label from the paragraph in order to define new physical content. This way, your paragraph will not interfere with the label as long as the label's container occupies the available space.

Here is my solution *(Not the greatest, but it does the work)*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --data-span-width: 20px;
  --data-title-width: 130px;
  --data-p-width: 1fr;
  --data-p-min-width: 100px;
  --data-aside-p-width: 100px;
}


.box {
  width: 75vw;
  min-width: 575px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}



/* Data row */
.box .data {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    var(--data-title-width)
    var(--data-span-width)
    var(--data-p-width);
}

.box .data > label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box .data > p:last-child {
  word-break: break-all;
  min-width: var(--data-p-min-width);
}



/* Data with another Data, but on the right side */
.box > .aside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box > .aside > .data:last-child {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.box > .aside > .data:last-child p:last-child {
  width: var(--data-aside-p-width);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box">

    <div class="aside">
      <div class="data">
        <label>Patient Name</label><span>:</span>
        <p>A Looooooonnnnnngggggg Naaaammmee</p>
      </div>
      <div class="data">
        <label>Patient ID</label><span>:</span>
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="aside">
      <div class="data">
        <label>C/o-(Brought By)</label><span>:</span>
        <p>P S S Raj</p>
      </div>
      <div class="data">
        <label>Patient Gender</label><span>:</span>
        <p>Male</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="aside">
      <div class="data">
        <label>Patient Age</label><span>:</span>
        <p>18 Yrs</p>
      </div>
      <div class="data">
        <label>Contact Number</label><span>:</span>
        <p>+923 999 9999 999</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="data">
      <label>Patient Address</label><span>:</span>
      <p>A Verrrrryyyyyyy Loooooooonnnnnggggggg Addddddddddddddrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeesssssssssssssss</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```